# Select (display) one of three different Webpart Forms based on a Users list item value; a, b, or c

Tags: 2010

All forms and lists referred to in SPD2010.

I have a list (Employee Appraisal) that contains all of the data needed for the user to complete one of three different forms (Web Parts).  The form to use depends on the type of User in the list; Associate, Professional, Manager.  Each type has a different web part form associated to it.  Using Webpart connections in SPD, I can only connect to 1 of the webparts.  The connections mamnger only allows one connection to the list.

I have a lookup working to get the user.  As the User List info is loaded, how can I get the correct form to display?  I have included the Webpart URL in the specific list, but cannot figure how the use the Webpart URL to display with the user information.

The Add/Manage connections only allows for one form to be connected to the Appraisal list.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you say it only allows for a single connection, but nevertheless i'm positive that via SharePoint Designer you could establish multiple filtering connections (make sure you use Data Parameters - which should also be supported by your Consumer web parts, e.g. a consumer should use the passed-in parameter to filter its content).

Examples here http://sarahlhaase.wordpress.com/2012/05/21/connecting-web-parts-with-a-selector-and-a-detail-pane-moss-2007-version/ (works on 2010 too) or http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-designer-help/connect-two-data-views-HA010169133.aspx

On this site another request similar [How to use "Get Parameters From" of "Web Part Connection Wizard" (SPD 2010)?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/37567/how-to-use-get-parameters-from-of-web-part-connection-wizard-spd-2010)

Answer (score 0):

You can add code to the page in a content editor web part to handle the switching. See the answer at [how to hide webpart in Home.aspx based on some condition](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/57266/how-to-hide-webpart-in-home-aspx-based-on-some-condition) for an example